# How to merge two hashes with same ID by combining keys with different values

Tags: ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes as follows:

```
hashes = [
  {id: 1, value: 'something', source: 'a'},
  {id: 1, value: 'something', source: 'b'},
  {id: 2, value: 'something', source: 'a'},
  {id: 3, value: 'something', source: 'c'}
]
```

I need this:

```
new_hashes = [
  {id: 1, value: 'something', source: ['a', 'b']},
  {id: 2, value: 'something', source: ['a']},
  {id: 3, value: 'something', source: ['c']}
]
```

How do I do this? I've tried the following:

```
merge_array = -> x,y { x.merge(y){|key, old, new| Array(old).push(new)} }
hashes.reduce &merge_array
```

But this merges everything together. I don't want to merge hashes with different ID.

Comment: What code have you tried writing yet ? Please show your attempt

Comment: It has nothing to do with Rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
hashes.
    group_by { |e| [e[:id], e[:value]] }.
    map { |_, g|
      g.first.clone.
          tap { |t|
            t[:source] = g.reduce([]) { |a, e| a << e[:source] }
          }
    }
```

First group the hashes by the part that should be the same. We don't care about the key any more; but each group itself will map to something very similar to the first element of the group. Clone it so the original `hashes` elements are not mutated; then replace its `:source` with the accumulation of all the group's elements' `:source` values.

Comment: The inards of `map`'s block could alternatively be written `g.first.merge(source: g.reduce([]) { |a, e| a << e[:source] })`.

Answer (score 3):

@Amadan used [Enumerable#group_by](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by) in his answer. `group_by` and `Enumerable#update` (aka `merge!`) are interchangeable in the sense that when one is used the other can <strike>usually</strike> be used instead. I will show how `update` can be used here.

```
hashes.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:id] => g.merge(source: [g[:source]])) do |_,oh,nh|
    oh.merge(source: oh[:source] + nh[:source])
  end
end.values
  #=> [{:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["a", "b"]},
  #    {:id=>2, :value=>"something", :source=>["a"]},
  #    {:id=>3, :value=>"something", :source=>["c"]}]
```

First, note that `h.update(k=>v)` is shorthand for `h.update({ k=>v })`. This uses the form of [Hash#update](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged. That block has three block variables, the common key (`_`), the value of the hash being updated (`oh`, "o" for "old", "h" because the value is a hash) and the value of the hash being merged (`nh`, "n" for "new").

The steps are as follows.

```
e = hashes.each_with_object({})
  #=> #<Enumerator: [
  #     {:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>"a"},
  #     {:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>"b"},
  #     {:id=>2, :value=>"something", :source=>"a"}, 
  #     {:id=>3, :value=>"something", :source=>"c"}
  #   ]:each_with_object({})>
```

The first element of this enumerator is generated, passed to the block and assigned to the block variables.

```
g,h = e.next
  #=> [{:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>"a"}, {}] 
g #=> {:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>"a"} 
h #=> {}
```

The block calculation is then performed.

```
h.update(g[:id]  => g.merge(source: [g[:source]]))
  #=> h.update(1 => g.merge(source: ["a"]))
  #=> h.update(1 =>{:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["b"]})
  #=> {1=>{:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["b"]}}
```

Prior to executing this merge `h` was empty, meaning that the two hashes being merged had no common keys. `update`'s value-resolution block was therefore not called.

Now `e` is directed by `update` to generate its next value and pass it to the block. The block variables are assigned to that value and the block calculation is performed.

```
g,h = e.next
  #=> [{:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>"b"},
  #    {1=>{:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["a"]}}] 
g #=>  {:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>"b"} 
h #=>  {1=>{:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["a"]}}
```

Notice that `h` has been updated. Now compute:

```
h.update(g[:id] => g.merge(source: [g[:source]])) do |_,oh,nh|
  oh.merge(source: oh[:source] + nh[:source])
end
  #=> {1=>{:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["a", "b"]}}
```

As

```
g[:id]
  #=> 1
```

and

```
g.merge(source: [g[:source]])
  #=> g.merge(source: ["b"])
  #=> {:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["b"]}
```

the above expression reduces to

```
h.update(1 => {:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["b"]}) do |_,oh,nh|
  oh.merge(source: oh[:source] + nh[:source])
end
```

As both hashes being merged have a common key of `1`, the block is called to determine the value of `1` in the merged hash:

```
_ = 1
oh = h[1]
  #=> {:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["a"]}
nh = g.merge(source: [g[:source]]) 
  #=> g.merge(source: ["b"])
  #=> {:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["b"]}
```

I've used an underscore (a valid local variable name) to represent the common key to signal to the reader that it is not used in the block calculation. The block calculation follows.

```
oh.merge(source: oh[:source] + nh[:source])
  #=> oh.merge(source: ["a", "b"])  
  #=> {:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["a", "b"]}
```

The calculations are similar for the remaining elements generated by `e`. We thereby obtain:

```
f = hashes.each_with_object({}) do |g,h|
  h.update(g[:id] => g.merge(source: [g[:source]])) do |_,oh,nh|
    oh.merge(source: oh[:source] + nh[:source])
  end
end
  #=> {1=>{:id=>1, :value=>"something", :source=>["a", "b"]},
  #    2=>{:id=>2, :value=>"something", :source=>["a"]},
  #    3=>{:id=>3, :value=>"something", :source=>["c"]}}
```

The final step is to return `f.values`.